# Trying to read a resource file from within a jar

Tags: java, url, io, classloader, getresource

I have read every single question and answer regarding this topic and I have tried a multitude of the suggested solutions, none of which are working, currently I am trying to use the URL resource method but url always returns null.  Here is my current pseudo setup:

/src/java/pkg/name/is/long/meatpackage/MyClassFile.java

/src/java/pkg/name/is/long/meatpackage/myresources/myresourcefile.txt

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Class thisClass = Class.forName("pkg.name.is.long.meatpackage.MyClassFile");
ClassLoader cLoader = thisClass.getClassLoader();
//note, I have tried a plethora of variations to the path for the file, this is just one example
URL url = cLoader.getResource("pkg/name/is/long/meatpackage/myresources/myresourcefile.txt");
System.out.println("Found the file!!: " + url);
```

Seriously, it can't be THIS hard to include a text file in your jar and access it at runtime can it?

When I list the jar it shows that the file is in pkg/name/is/log/meatpackage/myresources/myresourcefile.txt.

Another approach I have tried is:

```
//along with multiple path combinations for the file the InputStream is always null.    
//multiple paths include but are not limited to:
// "pkg/name/is/long/meatpackage/myresources/myresourcefile.txt"
// "/pkg/name/is/long/meatpackage/myresources/myresourcefile.txt"
// "/myresources/myresourcefile.txt"
// "/myresourcefile.txt"
// "myresourcefile.txt"
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myresourcefile.txt"); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this using getClass().getResourceAsStream() or MyClassFile.getResourceAsStream() - you don't need to talk to the classloader directly.

Note that the resource name is slash separated, and if you specify / then it's from the root of the JAR or from the base of the class path, otherwise it's implicitly from the same package directory as the class is.

For example:

package com.example;
  public class Foo {
    static {
      Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("bar.txt"); // looks for /com/example/bar.txt
      Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/bar.txt"); // looks for /bar.txt
    }
  }

If you're developing inside Eclipse, note that the `getResourceAsStream` only looks inside the compiled output directory (i.e. whatever is in `bin`). So if you have your resource outside of there, copy it into the `src` directory (so it gets copied over to the `bin` directory at build time) and it should find it properly.

Comment: So, does the method where this is being called need to be static?  I've tried this prior to posting because it's one of the suggestions on a similar question but just to be sure I tried it again a few minutes ago.  Neither methods of getResourceAsStream returns a non null InputStream.  Again, when I list the contents of the jar the file is there and I have tried putting the file in just about every location you can think of.  While it's really only appropriate to put it in a resources directory in the same package with the class, I have tried moving it up the directory structure nothing works.

Comment: Static didn't make a difference.. I changed the method to static and used the MyClassFile.class.getResourceAsStream to no avail.  I am ready to give up ..

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be static. Verify that your file is in the compiled output directory, and ensure the file reference begins with / if you want to put in the fully qualified package.

Comment: I verified that the file is in the compiled jar and I have tried every combination of path imaginable .. I have also tried moving the file to various locations within the project.  I finally gave up and just put the contents of the file in a class.. seems a silly thing to do but it is what it is and the sprint deadline is rapidly approaching..